# Can sole resources be added to the table of contents?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

This

```
FORMAT: 1A
HOST: something.com

# Something API    

# Group Something
    Foobar description
## Some Route [/routeroute]
    Foobar description
### Some HTML Action [GET]
+ Response 200 (text/plain)

# Group Something 2
    Foobar description 2
## Some Route [/routeroute2]
    Foobar description 2
### Some HTML Action 2 [GET]
+ Response 200 (text/plain)
```

generates     [image: this table of contents]

Now this:

```
FORMAT: 1A
HOST: something.com

# Something API    

# Some Route [/routeroute]
        Foobar description
## Some HTML Action [GET]
+ Response 200 (text/plain)

# Some Route 2 [/routeroute2]
        Foobar description 2
## Some HTML Action 2 [GET]
+ Response 200 (text/plain)
```

generates     [image]

**Why aren't individual resources part of the table of contents in Apiary?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in the current Apiary interactive documentation. However we are working on the [next-gen documentation](http://blog.apiary.io/2014/03/20/Re-API-Design-for-Humans/) where resource are indeed part of the TOC.

E.g:

[image: TOC]

---

To opt-in for the next-gen documentation beta look for the "New Documentation" switch in your API settings.